# Oracle 12c:Unable to login using jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Recently we have had to perform a test for application server.For that we created a replica of existing tables by creating new user in database. We are using `oracle 12c`. `userB` is newly created user in database. We have taken the replica from `userA`. But strangely when I am connecting to database using java code , it works for `userA` and does not work for `userB` and I get `ORA 01017` error . When I connect using GUI like oracle sql developer , it works for both users .I am not aware of which database log files to look at.Are there any precautions we should take while dumping tables from `userA` to `userB` ? Please suggest

Comment: ORA-1017 means the password being sent to the database is not correct - that could either mean it literally is not the same password (which is the most frequent scenario) or it is being hashed and sent with a too-old method for the database to accept securely. If you are sure you have the password correct, make sure the JDBC driver being used by your application is recent enough (you can check what version the database wants for the user with `dba_users.password_versions`)

Comment: @AndrewSayer thanks for the suggestion. I am giving plain text password for testing purposes. Still we are getting same error

Comment: Have you checked the versions you are running? 12c could also mean 2 very distinct versions.